# Why does this Highcharts graph only show tooltip for the first and last nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm just starting out with Highcharts and I'm having a little trouble showing a tooltip for each data item in my graph. At the moment, it just shows a tooltip for the first and last item.

```
var chart1; // globally available

$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'AssessmentChart',
            marginRight: 100,
            marginBottom: 40
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Assessment history',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Assessment history for this patient',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Score'
            },
            max: 72,
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.y +'</b>';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: []
    };

    // Get the main assessment data...
    var dlqiData = [], hdnDlqiData = $("#hdnDlqiData");

    if (hdnDlqiData.length > 0) {
        var dlqiDataJson = $.parseJSON(hdnDlqiData.val());

        $.each(dlqiDataJson, function (i, item) {
            dlqiData.push(
                {
                    x: stringToUtcDate(item.dateCreated),
                    y: item.calculatedScore
                }
            );
        });

        options.series.push({
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'DLQI',
            data: dlqiData
        });
    }

    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    function stringToUtcDate(datestring) {
        var date = datestring.split('/');

        return Date.UTC(parseInt(date[2], 10), parseInt(date[1], 10) - 1, parseInt(date[0], 10));
    }

});​
```

I'm pulling data in from a hidden form field, so here's a Fiddle showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gfyans/LjRGk/3/

Here's one of the official Fiddle's, http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/, and they manage it OK, but I can't see from that what I'm dong wrong/differently.

I know it'll be something insanely easy, but I can't see it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Greg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have your data in ascending date order if using a datetime x-axis.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Thanks.